# PyTorch not updating weights when using autograd in loss function

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I am trying to use the gradient of a network with respect to its inputs as part of my loss function. However, whenever I try to calculate it, the training proceeds but the weights do not update

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.autograd as autograd


ic = torch.rand((25, 3))
ic = torch.tensor(ic, requires_grad=True)
optimizer = optim.RMSprop([ic], lr=1e-2)

for itr in range(1, 50):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    sol = torch.tanh(.5*torch.stack(100*[ic])) # simplified for minimal working example
    
    dx = sol[-1, :, 0]
    dxdxy, = autograd.grad(dx, 
                           inputs=ic,
                           grad_outputs = torch.ones(ic.shape[0]), # batchwise
                           retain_graph=True
                          )
    dxdxy = torch.tensor(dxdxy, requires_grad=True)
    loss = torch.sum(dxdxy)
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if itr % 5 == 0:
        print(loss)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `autograd.grad` without setting flag `create_graph` to `True` then you won't obtain an output which is connected to the computational graph, which means that you won't be able to further optimize w.r.t `ic` (and obtain a higher order derivative as you wish to do here).
From `torch.autograd.grad`'s docstring:

> create_graph (bool, optional): If `True`, graph of the derivative will
> be constructed, allowing to compute higher order derivative products.
> Default: `False`.

Using `dxdxy = torch.tensor(dxdxy, requires_grad=True)` as you've tried here won't help since the computational graph which is connected to `ic` has been lost by then (since `create_graph` is `False`), and all you do is create a new computational graph with `dxdxy` being a leaf node.

See the solution attached below (note that when you create `ic` you can set `requires_grad=True` and hence the second line is redundant (that's not a logical problem but just longer code):

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.autograd as autograd

ic = torch.rand((25, 3),requires_grad=True) #<-- requires_grad to True here
#ic = torch.tensor(ic, requires_grad=True) #<-- redundant
optimizer = optim.RMSprop([ic], lr=1e-2)

for itr in range(1, 50):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    sol = torch.tanh(.5 * torch.stack(100 * [ic]))  # simplified for minimal working example

    dx = sol[-1, :, 0]
    dxdxy, = autograd.grad(dx,
                           inputs=ic,
                           grad_outputs=torch.ones(ic.shape[0]),  # batchwise
                           retain_graph=True, create_graph=True # <-- important
                           )
    #dxdxy = torch.tensor(dxdxy, requires_grad=True) #<-- won't do the trick. Remove
    loss = torch.sum(dxdxy)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if itr % 5 == 0:
        print(loss)
```